# Grid pattern made out of thin wood slats or MDF

Tags: wood, plywood, mdf, storage, materials

Can the wood slats or MDF be purchased pre-cut ready to assemble? If available does this product go by another name? I have read the article detailing how to make this using carpentry equipment but I am interested in buying them pre slotted for assembly. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: "Can _the_ wood slats...". "I have read _the_ article..." Care to elaborate? My local big-box home improvement center sells loads of wood in a wide variety of sizes. My local dedicated lumber yard will be happy to mill to just about any size I care to specify. So yes, it's _highly_ likely that you can get exactly what you need, but you may end up paying more for it than you'd like to. Please [edit] your post to include a link to "the article" and maybe even a link to "the project" detailing "_the_ wood slats".

Comment: @FreeMan It's not uncommon for non-native speakers of English to mistakenly use a definite article ("the") in place of an indefinite article ("a"). The question makes more sense if you make that substitution.

Comment: This is true, @Caleb, however, that still leaves the question of what size wood slats the OP is after. It seems he's after something very specific, but hasn't given any specifics, making it difficult to answer the question. My local big box sells 1x2" and 1x3" furring strips which could be "slats", but I also think of the wood slats used to make lattice panels, and they're much smaller than a 1x2, and aren't (to my knowledge) sold at my local big-box store.

Comment: @FreeMan I didn't even think of furring strips! Hope you won't mind if I add that to my answer.

Comment: I think the OP is looking to make a grid, hence the key part of the Q, *"pre slotted for assembly"* So he's looking for wood (of an indeterminate width and thickness) with edge laps/cross laps, AKA cross halving joints, already machined into one edge.

Answer (score 1):

> Can <strike>the</strike> wood slats or MDF be purchased pre-cut ready to assemble?

Depending on how you want to assemble them, yes. Most home centers sell strips known as *lath*, usually in bundles of 50. The strips are usually about 1 1/2" wide, 1/4" or 5/16" thick, and 4' or 6' long.

Lath strips used to be used as the foundation for plaster walls: they were nailed to bare wall studs with spaces, and then the plaster was applied over them and pushed through them. As the plaster oozed through the spaces, it would droop on the far side and naturally form a sort of hook that secured the plaster to the wall. These days, of course, sheet rock is much more common, but you can still get the lath strips.

I don't know what project you have in mind, but lath strips could be assembled into lattice for fencing, a trellis, etc.

Strips in other sizes are also available, and go by different names depending on their size and customary use. *Furring strips* are nominally 1" thick (so really closer to 3/4") and 2", 3", or 4" wide. *Moulding* and *casing* are two names for strips that usually have fancy profiles but may be plain, and which come in a variety of styles.